# how to create multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, charts

In my project i am using highcart for that i should give the input in below format.

Here is my sample data:

```
[{"A",23},{"B",24},{"C",25},{"D",26},{"E",27}]
```

I have to convert the above json array to below format.

```
data=[["A",23],["B",24],["C",25],["D",26],["E",27]]
```

How to iterate my sample data and convert the above format.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I dont believe your sample data is valid. What is the format exactly? {} these parenthesis are used to indicate objects, but your keys dont have associated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[{"A",23},{"B",24},{"C",25},{"D",26},{"E",27}]` is wrong,
it should be like `[{"A":23},{"B":24},{"C":25},{"D":26},{"E":27}];`

```js
var data = [{"A":23},{"B":24},{"C":25},{"D":26},{"E":27}];
var newData = [];
data.forEach(function(val,index){
    var keys = Object.keys(val);
    keys.push(val[keys]);
    newData.push(keys);
    
});
alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
```